# Error in json_decode

Tags: php, json

I have the following json, I'm sending through AJAX, but in the server side the json_decode returning an empty array. I'm sending different values as well, and in that case it's working fine. I check int this [link](http://jsonlint.com/), and this is a valid JSON.

```
[
    {
        "name": "bettype",
        "value": "All"
    },
    {
        "name": "bookies",
        "value": "Interwetten"
    },
    {
        "name": "sporttype",
        "value": "Soccer"
    },
    {
        "name": "team1",
        "value": "Braunschweig"
    },
    {
        "name": "team2",
        "value": "Bayern Munich"
    },
    {
        "name": "league",
        "value": "Germany DFB Cup (90`)"
    }
]
```

UPDATED:

this is the server side code:

```
var_dump((stripslashes($_GET['data']));
var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data'])));
```

and this is the output:

```
string(244) "[{"name":"bettype","value":"All"},{"name":"bookies","value":"Interwetten"},{"name":"sporttype","value":"Soccer"},{"name":"team1","value":"Braunschweig"},{"name":"team2","value":"Bayern Munich"},{"name":"league","value":"Germany DFB Cup (90�)"}]" NULL
```

Comment: Works fine here. You're going to have to do better than that.

Comment: what is this sign ` , in Germany DFB Cup (90`)

Comment: Probably buggy json decoder which cannot decode [ ] arrays, but needs object { } as the root

Comment: I guess the problem is ` sign, because I'm sending other datas, and with that is working fine.

Comment: if you are dealing with `$_GET`, maybe you can take a look on urlencode & urldecode function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/80941.php

Check your browser configuration/charset and try again